# angular 2+ multiple component import management

Tags: angular

I have a component (lets call in "main") that have a specific purpose:

- opening bootstrap modal that will contain different components.
- the component that is shown in the modal is depended on what element I have
  clicked on in my "main" component to open the modal.

Now as I understand this, for using those components I need to import them.
But importing all the options of components seems messy at least...
I've read about lazy loading for modules but for that I need different routes for each and here I'm using the same page to show different components.

Is there a lazy component loading?
Found [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28) when searched for solution, should it be my direction? is it good practice? and if not, what is the best way to approach this?

thanks.

Comment: Lazy loading and dynamic loading are two different things. Lazy loading requires a module, so if you want you can have many modules for each component you have. The article you linked explains dynamic loading. You still need to import those components or a shared module in your module.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Yes you are right of course. But then again I'm entering the problem that: Lazy loading = new URLs that makes new pages (maybe I'm wrong?). Dynamic loading = as you said, I still need to import all those components...

Comment: Exactly, you have to do some routing. You could keep the url as is (skipLocationChange) but in reality, that page is in different route. So, I think what you need is dynamic loading. I'm afraid you can't utilize lazy loading in your case.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner hmm maybe I'm failing to understand something important here... when you import the component at the top of the .ts file, does't it require some build/work from the app in run time? what I want to understand is: is it a bad thing to import many many components when in reality the user will use only few of them

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I understand that importing a component doesn't build it (entering constructor etc). but does it require from the app resources on run or build time?